# Getting all rows that have all of the entered values by querying the same column

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

I am trying to search for all users that have all of the entered tags but it is searching for them by looking in the same column.

```
SELECT u.*, t.* FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_tags ut ON u.id = ut.user_id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON ut.tag_id = t.id
WHERE t.name = tag1 AND t.name = tag2
```

I am searching solely by tag and each user must have all of the entered tags, not just 1. I'm using PHP to add another AND clause based on the number of values entered so if there are 3 values, it will look like this:

```
SELECT u.*, t.* FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_tags ut ON u.id = ut.user_id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON ut.tag_id = t.id
WHERE t.name = tag1 AND t.name = tag2 AND t.name = tag3
```

t.name only contains 1 tag name, not a comma-separated value. The tag names are linked to each user through the user_tags table where each user id can multiple tag ids like so:

```
user_id | tag_id
40      | 3
40      | 4
41      | 1
41      | 2
41      | 3
```

And my current query returns nothing because none of the columns have all 3 tag names.

Comment: So i'm guessing t.name is a comma delimited field? Going to have to string search with `LIKE`

Comment: Can you tell us more about what is stored in t.name?

Comment: can you add sample records with desired result?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please always provide all details that are relevant to your problem. In this case (in addition to what's been mentioned): What is the table structure? What data do you store in it, is it encoded in some special format?

Comment: No, unfortunately. t.name can only have one tag and t.name only has a tag name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be the following where 'count' would be the amount of tags you're querying for, so you'll only get the users who have all the specified tags.

```
SELECT u.*, count(*) as `count`
FROM `user` u 
    JOIN `user_tags` ut ON ut.`user_id`=u.`id`
    JOIN `tags` t ON t.`id`=ut.`tag_id`
WHERE t.`name`='tag1' OR t.`name`='tag2'
GROUP BY u.`id`
HAVING `count` = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.  It will only return user id's that have all 3 tags.

```
SELECT    u.id
FROM      user u
          LEFT JOIN user_tags ut ON u.id = ut.user_id
          LEFT JOIN tags t ON ut.tag_id = t.id
GROUP BY  u.id
HAVING        SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = tag1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
          AND SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = tag2 THEN 1 ELSE 0) > 0 
          AND SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = tag3 THEN 1 ELSE 0) > 0
```

Comment: Great answer.  However, it will be slightly faster using inner join and an extra ON clause, e.g.: INNER JOIN user_tags ut ON u.id = ut.user_id INNER JOIN tags t ON ut.tag_id = t.id AND t.name IN (tag1, tag2, tag3) - this will eliminate users with none of the tags 1, 2, or 3 before getting to the HAVING clause.

Comment: Good point.  I was thinking that there were only going to be the 3 tags.  But it's possible that there are more out there.  I couldn't really tell by the question.

Comment: It's not only that, but what about users who have no tags specified at all?  You want to eliminate them as well before getting to the group.  Note also, I added another solution below that uses no groups, which should be very high-performance.

Comment: I think your idea of using INNER JOINS with IN (tag1, tag2, tag3) would be faster than joining the results of 3 separate self joins.  You'd be hitting the table once instead of 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

lets use group_concat...

```sql
SELECT
    u.*
FROM
    user u
    JOIN user_tags ut ON ut.user_id = y.id
    JOIN tags t ON t.id = ut.tag_id
WHERE
-- limit only the tags you want
    t.name IN ( tag1, tag2, ... )
GROUP BY
    u.id
HAVING
    GROUP_CONCAT( t.name ORDER BY t.name SEPARATOR ',' ) = 'tag1,tag2,...'
```

note that, in the having section, tag order should be same in both sides of condition